# How can I know what parts a manufacturer uses in their schematic?

Tags: schematics

I have an old printer, and I have the schematics from HP.  The image is below.  They have names on the parts, but if I look up something like "PM706," I can't get anything.

How can I find out what a manufacturers parts are *from the schematic*?  Is it possible?  I don't want to take things apart, if I don't have to.

[image]

Comment: You flip to the bill of materials. No BoM? SoL.

Comment: You can't get from the schematic more than it is containing. If it has a motor labeled "PM706", the only thing you can know it is a motor the HP guys know under the name PM706. So if google doesn't help, only the HP guys can.

Comment: You're not meant to. A schematic serves two purposes - generation of a netlist for PCB layout, and visual representation of the interconnections for easy debugging. Parts are usually abstracted away by reference designators, which tie into bills of material and approved vendor lists to figure out exactly what part PS714 actually *is*. Too much information for a schematic in most cases considering alternates, multi-vendor parts, etc.

Comment: You might not be able to identify parts even if you 'take things apart'. HP are a large enough customer that the may have custom parts made, or their own designation put on parts. This likely won't apply to high-volume generic parts, but may apply to sensors, encoders,  motors, etc. SO even with the part in your hand, you might not get a part number with meaning outside HP. (We took an old HP printer apart and IIRC some parts had no other designation on them).

Comment: Table 50. Feed drive assembly—optional tray 3. Description: Motor (M706), tray 3. **Part number: RH7-1536-000CN**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many years ago HP, as a big volume manufacturer, used IC components (and transistors, and other parts) from huge variety of manufacturers, but all of them had proprietary HP-specific markings. 
Without a special cross-reference list ([like this one](http://www.sphere.bc.ca/download/hp_xref-free.pdf)) it is not possible to establish correspondence with common parts, although they almost all have exact original substitutions.

Comment: or "can be substituted with exact same originals" :-)

Answer (score 2):

The image provided is not a full schematic. Circuit schematics have two (at least) designations for each part: a part code and a part number. If both are not shown directly on the schematic, a separate document (the bill of materials, or BOM) will provide the cross-reference.

The part number is what you want if you are looking for replacements - in other words, you want the designation for the part used by its manufacturer (e.g. Texas Instruments, Murata, Intersil,...)

The diagram you are showing only has the part codes, which are designations generated by the design engineer for his/her own bookkeeping purposes. The letter prefix follows some semi-standard codes, and the number is arbitrary (but unique for a given system).

- Q100 = transistor #100
- R34 = resistor #34
- J324 = connector #324

In other words, part codes do not exist outside of the given assembly/circuit board and you won't find them in a part number search.

Answer (score 1):

The image you show is NOT a circuit diagram.  It is a block diagram that shows on a higher-level what the blocks are and how they connect to each other.  There is a lower-level, more-detailed drawing that shows the actual circuit details down to component level.

"PM706" is NOT a part number. It is a Reference Designator.  Like R7 or C3.  Very likely: "PM" means "pickup motor" (or similar).  And "7" is the likely the major section of the printer (like the input paper handling part), and "06" designates that this is motor #6 in that section of the printer.

There are other documents that actually identify the motor called "PM706".  However, it is certainly a custom part made for HP and the part number on the motor is a "house number" from HP.

You don't reveal WHY you want to "look up" the motor. But the chances of researching anything useful ranges between slim and none. You have no practical choice but to actually measure and experiment with the motor yourself.